# Checking for two categories in query_posts

Tags: categories, query-posts

How can I check two category_name values in the following query_post?

```
 <?php query_posts('category_name=recent-work&posts_per_page=1');
   if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
```

So that it reads something like this:

```
 <?php query_posts('category_name=recent-work&&category_name=plumbing&posts_per_page=1');
   if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
```

Many thanks.

**EDIT:**

```
<?php
        $querySimilarWork = new WP_Query( array(
            'tax_query' => array(
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'categories',
                    'field' => 'slug',
                    'terms' => array( 'recent-work', 'plumbing' )
                )
            ),
            'posts_per_page' => 4
        );
    ?>
```

**EDIT:**

If I now query this WP_query, it doesn't return anything?

```
<?php while ($querySimilarWork->have_posts()) : $querySimilarWork->the_post(); ?>
    <li><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a>   
    </li>
 <?php endwhile; ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `query_posts`. Use [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query), and use it's [`tax_query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters).

```
$query = new WP_Query( array(
    ...
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'category',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => array( 'recent-work', 'plumbing', 'cat3' )
        )
    ),
    'posts_per_page' => 1
    ...
);
```

Comment: Hi Eric. I'm not sure where I am going wrong with this. I have read the Codex, looked at more examples on the web as well as used two different WP_Query generators to see if I am missing something but every time I implement this, I keep getting  

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';' in E:\Websites\Xampp-1.7.7\htdocs\....\content-sidebar-page.php on line 109

If delete the EDIT above, all's good and well again?

Comment: You're missing a closing `)`. You need 2 at the end - `WP_Query( array( ... ) );`

Comment: Eric, I've made another edit. If I now loop over those posts,  nothing is returned? Is the taxonomy of 'categories' correct? Thanks again.

Comment: No, it's actually `category`. Updated my example, sorry for that.